# Have to press twice to delete item in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to delete item in redux toolkit, but don't know how, the remove function only work on screen, i have to press twice to delete the previous one,

Here is the reducer

```js
const noteReducer = createSlice({
  name: "note",
  initialState: NoteList,
  reducers: {
    addNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      const newNote: NoteI = {
        id: new Date(),
        header: action.payload.header,
        note: action.payload.note,
        date: new Date(),
        selectStatus: false,
      };
      state.push(newNote);
    },
    removeNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => { // 
 ======> Problem here
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    toggleSelect: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          return { ...item, selectStatus: !item.selectStatus };
        }
        return item;
      });
    },
    loadDefault: (state) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        return { ...item, selectStatus: false };
      });
    },
    resetNote: (state) => {
      return (state = []);
    },

    editNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            note: action.payload.note,
            header: action.payload.header,
            date: action.payload.date,
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchNote.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = [];
      return state.concat(action.payload);
     
    });
    
  },
});
```

Here is the function where i use it:

```js
export default function NoteList(props: noteListI) {
  const { title, note, id, date } = props;
  const data = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.persistedReducer.note);
  const removeSelectedNote = () => {
    dispatch(removeNote({ id: id }));
    console.log(data);  ====> still log 4 if i have 4
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onLongPress={() => {
          removeSelectedNote();
        }}
        // flex
        style={CONTAINER}
        onPress={() =>
          !toggleSelectedButton ? onNavDetail() : setEnableToggle()
        }
      >
        <Note
          note={note}
          header={title}
          date={date}
          id={id}
          selectedStatus={selectedButtonStatus}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have to press twice to make it work, for example, i have 4 item, when i press one, the item on screen disappears  but the data log still have 4 item, when i click another, it show 3 on console.log but the screen display 2, i mean the function maybe work correctly but i want to update the state also, how can i do that?
Or how can i update the state if i remove item in redux-toolkit?

When i log the data on the redux, it return correct: 3
[image]

Here is a gif to show what going on

[image]

**UPDATED**

As @Janik suggest, i use console.log in function, so it log correct

[image]

**But how can i get this change?** I mean, it log correct, but i was fetch data from firebase so i need to log this data to make change to firebase, so how can i do that, i try to put it in a function:

```js
const getNote = useCallback(() => {
    setCurrentNote(data);
  }, [data]);
```

But it show this error:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:184 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is your logged `data` coming from?

I suppose this is just a matter of order and timing, when your log happens within the [React Lifecycle „Update“](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp).

If `data` references your state:

1. component is rendered initially, `data` is 4.
2. Note removed, still in the same rendering state, therefore `data` still is 4
3. React re-renders your component, `data` is 3.

To check on this, you can try changing the order by moving the `console.log` outside of the `removeSelectedNote`. This way, log will happen on step 1 and 3 instead of 2

Comment: I update the question, data is from redux state @Janik, sorry for this late, but it work like you said when l log in the component, but problem is, how can i get these change, i tried to put in a useState but when i call the function and log data, it still have 4 items, i upated in the question, please see it, thank you so much